# How can I Identify if client terminate the call to my SpringBoot API unexpectedly (before being able to return the respond back)

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I have a SpringBoot/Jersey application which exposes Restful POST API's.
I need to identify cases where clients terminated the request unexpectedly before getting the response back.

Any idea how can I identify such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a Servlet and use it to write the response back to the user. In the servlet you should have access to the OutputStream which should throw an Exception when the client closed the connection.
https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet